# suse12: how to set default route via config file

Tags: linux, networking, routing, opensuse, suse

I've got some systems that are provisioning SLES12sp1 statelessly - the systems come up with their provisioning interface configured, but no default route.

On RedHat I'd set the `GATEWAYDEV` in `/etc/sysconfig/network` -- but I can't find an equivalent for openSUSE/SLES.

There is no NetworkManager or `ifcfg` files:

```
# ls /etc/sysconfig/network/
config  dhcp  if-down.d  if-up.d  ifcfg-lo  ifcfg.template  network  providers  scripts
```

Some additional context:

```
# ifconfig eth2
eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  
          inet addr:192.168.1.29  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:67ff:fecb:f26f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:213248 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:35744 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:295970393 (282.2 Mb)  TX bytes:4018621 (3.8 Mb)
          Memory:92020000-9203ffff 

# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0     U     0      0        0 eth2
```

Comment: Have you seen this page? https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled11/book_sle_admin/data/sec_basicnet_manconf.html

Comment: Yes -- the sle 12 version of that doc, but I haven't found anything in it that resolves my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create or edit `/etc/sysconfig/network/routes` and add a line like :

```
default 192.168.1.1 - -
```

(where, in case it would not be obvious, 192.168.1.1 is your gateway)

[src: courseware for Suse course 3124 "SUSE Linux Server 12 Administration"]

Comment: @heritu -- no luck. Tried `default <ip> - -`, `default <ip> - eth2`, `default - - eth2`. Maybe because PXE is bringing up the interface?

Comment: I think your answer is correct -- but won't work in my case because of how the provisioning is happening.